# Help understanding Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory

The book I'm reading defines the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups in the usual way that a finite abelian group is isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{e_1}} \times \cdots \times  \mathbb{Z}_{{p_r}^{e_r}}$, but then it also states that the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{m_1} \times \cdots \times  \mathbb{Z}_{m_t}$ where for each $i = 1,...,t-1$ we have $m_i | m_{i+1}$. How can this be if the groups orders are supposed to be relatively prime.

If anyone can give an example of how this works I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Well, for distinct primes $p_i$ and $p_j$, we have $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_j^{e_j}}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}p_j^{e_j}}$. This is true in general for coprime integers. This means you can move around the $p_i$ in a way that will allow you to do this; I'm not sure exactly what the proof is but that's a reason why it's possible.

Comment: Nothing says the group orders are relatively prime. For any prime $p$ the direct sum may involve cyclic groups of order $p^k$ for several $k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So if for example the group was $\mathbb{Z}_{15*3}$ this would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$?

Comment: @M.Smith no because $3$ is not coprime to $15$. But $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5\cong\mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's where I'm getting confused because then how can $m_i | m_{i+1}$ if they have to be coprime?

Comment: In the first decomposition theorem you stated, the $p_i$ are not necessarily distinct.  I hope someone writes an answer. The main problem is typographical, too many exponents and subscripts. I would prefer to give a sample example that illustrates the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of the *Chinese remainder theorem*. If the group orders are pairwise coprime, the product is isomorphic to $\;\mathbf Z/p_1^{e_1}\dots p_r^{e_r}\mathbf Z$, and there is only one such $m_i$ (which, incidentally, are called the *invariant factors* of the abelian group).

Here is an example:  suppose the primary decomposition of the group is:
$$\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/3^2\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/3^2\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/5\times\mathbf Z/5^2\mathbf Z\times  \mathbf Z/5^3\mathbf Z. $$
First display the primary factors on different lines (*one line per prime factor*) in *increasing order* of the exponent and *right-aligned*:
 $$\begin{array}{r}
\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z^{\phantom{2}}\\
 {}\times \mathbf Z/3^2\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/3^2\mathbf Z\\
  {}\times \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/5^2\mathbf Z\times  \mathbf Z/5^3\mathbf Z
\end{array}.  $$
Then apply the C.r.t. to each column:
$$ \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/225\mathbf Z\times  \mathbf Z/2250\mathbf Z.$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you give an example to illustrate how it's used?

Comment: @M. Smith: I've added an example. Hope it is clear.